# Jquery Mobile List Custom Filter Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change the default filter from Jquery Mobile lists, like that:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cherry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cranberry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Grape</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ul>
```

I found this page, from jquery mobile API documentation, that show how to do.

[Jquery Mobile Documentation Custom Filter Example](http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#custom-filter-example)

This is the code. It would search by the line number, and not by the text:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.filterable.prototype.options.filterCallback = function( index, searchValue ) {
        var idx;

        if ( searchValue ) {
            searchValue = searchValue.split( "," );
            searchValue = $.map( searchValue, function( element ) {
                var ar = element.split( "-" );
                    return ar.length === 1 ? parseInt( element ) :
                        [ [ parseInt( ar[ 0 ] ), parseInt( ar[ 1 ] ) ] ];
            });
            for ( idx = 0 ; idx < searchValue.length ; idx++ ) {
                if ( ( $.type( searchValue[ idx ] ) === "number" &&
                        index === searchValue[ idx ] ) ||
                    ( $.type( searchValue[ idx ] ) === "array" &&
                        index >= searchValue[ idx ][ 0 ] &&
                        index <= searchValue[ idx ][ 1 ] ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return !!searchValue;
    };
});
```

But, unfortunately, I couldn't make it work.

Here is what I did. The same code from the documentation above:

[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/TFE33/27/)

I hope someone helps me to find the solution ^^

And another question.

How will it work, if I use my javascripts at the end of the body?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: the code above should be placed in head after jQuery.js and before jQM.js because it's executed on `mobileinit` which fires even before `.ready()`.

Comment: Humm. Interesting. Thanks.
But even I putting the code after jquery js and before jquery mobile js, in my head, my page is breaking with the message $.mobile.filterable is undefined.
Do you know why?

Comment: You shouldn't bind it to `mobileinit`, use `pagecontainerecreate` instead. Because you want to override the default function before _filterable_ widget is created http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/TFE33/32/

Comment: Wow. Incredible. It works perfectly.
One last question, if possible.
Can I get the text from the index generic?
Because I just found results that need one id from some list.
After that, please post the answer to me accept.